# How can I convert extracted Mat Contours to Bitmap in Opencvsharp?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

After I applied the Threshold on the Destination Image
I get a Mat as Reference
then I called the function FindContours()
to extract all existed Contours on the target Image
finally I tried to convert the extracted contours one at a time to Bitmap  and here at this point am getting an Error:

System.ArgumentException: "Number of channels must be 1, 3 or 4. Parametername: src" by converting Mat to Bitmap

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog getImag = new OpenFileDialog();
    getImag.Filter = "PNG,JPG|*.png;*.jpg";

    DialogResult result = getImag.ShowDialog();
    string Source_Logo_Link = string.Empty;

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Source_Logo_Link = getImag.FileName;
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Source_Logo_Link);

        Mat src = new OpenCvSharp.Mat(Source_Logo_Link);
        OpenCvSharp.Mat gray = src.CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);

        OpenCvSharp.Mat binary = gray.Threshold(0, 255, ThresholdTypes.Otsu);
        OpenCvSharp.Mat[] contoursQuery;
            OutputArray hierarchyQ = InputOutputArray.Create(new List<Vec4i>());
        binary.FindContours(out contoursQuery, hierarchyQ, RetrievalModes.CComp, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxTC89KCOS);

        List<Bitmap> images = new List<Bitmap>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= contoursQuery.Length; i++)
            images.add(contoursQuery[i].toBitmap());
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry this comes a bit late, but I hope this still helps though. Apart from a few other issues (like the counter of the for loop), I guess that your major problem is, that you miss-understood the result of FindContours.
It really just gives you a list of all contour points, which it found in the image, not complete images.
Have a look at the documentation [FindContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a), it clearly states for the contour parameter:

> Each contour is stored as a vector of points

So that means if you wand them "one at a time to Bitmap" you'll need to create these bitmaps first, and then draw the contours into it. To make drawing a bit more easy (and faster) there is the [DrawContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc) command, which you could use for the drawing part.
Over all, in the end, it should look somehow like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog getImag = new OpenFileDialog();
   getImag.Filter = "PNG,JPG|*.png;*.jpg";

   DialogResult result = getImag.ShowDialog();
   string Source_Logo_Link = string.Empty;

   if (result == DialogResult.OK)
   {
        Source_Logo_Link = getImag.FileName;
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Source_Logo_Link);

        Mat src = new OpenCvSharp.Mat(Source_Logo_Link);
        OpenCvSharp.Mat gray = src.CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);

        OpenCvSharp.Mat binary = gray.Threshold(0, 255, ThresholdTypes.Otsu);

        // I'd really prefer to work with point lists and HierarchyIndex because 
        // it's much more descriptive that way
        OpenCvSharp.Point[][] contours;
        OpenCvSharp.HierarchyIndex[] hierarchyQ;

        binary.FindContours(out contours,out hierarchyQ, RetrievalModes.List, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxTC89KCOS);

        List<Bitmap> images = new List<Bitmap>();
        for (int i = 0; i < contoursQuery.Length; i++){
            var singleContour = new OpenCvSharp.Mat(src.Size(), MatType.CV_8U,0);
            singleContour.DrawContours(contours,i,Scalar.White);
            images.Add(singleContour.ToBitmap());
        }
    }    
}
```

I also changed the [RetrievalMode](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71) to "List", since you don't really seem to care about the hierarchical relationships.

Hope that helps ;-)